# I lose antialiasing when I change the renderer to painters in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I change the renderer in Matlab like this:

```
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters');
```

and the lines that were antialised with the default renderer, now are not antialiased anymore. By the way this is how I plot lines:

```
plot(x,y1,'LineWidth',2,'LineSmoothing','on','Color','r');
```

Thanks

Comment: Did MathWorks documented the `LineSmoothing` property already? If not, I'd expect any behavior of the lines that use it. See here for more details, for example: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-linesmoothing-property/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you're out of luck. The `painters` renderer is essentially bitmap only. Antialiasing and 3-D are only supported with the [other renderers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html#Renderer). Line smoothing is implemented with [Open GL](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter06.html). @anadr is correct also that the `'LineSmoothing'` property is actually undocumented. If you use it enough you'll discover that it can be buggy. You might try the `'zbuffer'` renderer if you can.